# Where does the term viridis (for color map) in matplotlib come from?

Tags: python, matplotlib

the default Colormap of matplotlib is viridis,

```
a = np.arange(6).reshape(2,3)
aimg = plt.imshow(a)
```

renders an image (figure_1)

[image]

```
aimg.cmap.name
```

outputs

```
'viridis'
```

which is not a normal English.

according to this [post](https://www.merriam-webster.com/words-at-play/green-words),

> The Latin word for “green” is viridis

but figure_1 looks like more colorful than green.

what does the term viridis in matplotlib come from?

Comment: Read [this](https://bids.github.io/colormap/) and watch the video on that page

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The source code says:

```
Matplotlib ships with 4 perceptually uniform color maps which are
the recommended color maps for sequential data:
  =========   ===================================================
  Colormap    Description
  =========   ===================================================
  inferno     perceptually uniform shades of black-red-yellow
  magma       perceptually uniform shades of black-red-white
  plasma      perceptually uniform shades of blue-red-yellow
  viridis     perceptually uniform shades of blue-green-yellow
  =========   ===================================================
```

I also found this:

> For an introduction to color theory and how 'viridis' was generated watch Nathaniel Smith and Stéfan van der Walt's talk from SciPy2015

Here's [that talk](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xAoljeRJ3lU)